# Exception Received Retry Command Error:Unexpected response ():

Tags: php, image, cron, rackspace-cloudfiles

we have a cron that runs a PHP script that processes xml files including processing images. (pulling them from a web address, resizing them and then uploading to CloudFiles.

we are finding that after 220 or so images that we get an error: Exception Received Retry Command Error:Unexpected response ():

we have coded the script to try 5 times to upload it (unfortunately it still fails) and then is to go to the NEXT IMAGE
Unfortunately it fails on the next image and then so on.

The container we are uploading to is not full, we only do 1 image at a time so below the 100/sec restrictions. Files are not large example: http://images.realestateview.com.au/pics/543/10157543ao.jpg" format="jpg"/>

We tried to then run the script again via our server with the image that failed and it worked successfully along with other images.

No idea why this is happening, RackSpace advise it is a issue with the script or the cron. But we are not convinced.

Happy to post script if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing 5 retries with any backoff time or just as fast as possible? If not currently, add exponential backoff to the retry attempts.